# modx wayfinder dynamic pictures

Tags: image, dynamic, menu, modx

I create Wayfinder by a small overview page (scale projects, etc.)

```
<li[[+wf.id]][[+wf.classes]]>
<div onclick='location.href="[[+wf.link]]"' class="[[+wf.title]] project_overview" title="[[+wf.title]]" [[+wf.attributes]]><img src="images/HausDummy.png" /></div>
[[+wf.wrapper]]
```

Here is to be displayed from child page in the first picture. In the inferior side multiple images are displayed in a gallery.

Is something like that feasible? By the dynamics behind me, I do something heavy.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Ich denke mal, wenn Du Deine Frage auf englisch stellst, bekommst Du mehr Antworten. ;)

Comment: danke ;) Habs mal geändert

Answer (score -2):

Old Question, but maybe someone else needs a hint for that..
Also the Question is not easy to understand (auf deutsch hätte ich sie besser verstanden ;) ),
to get images for your wayfinder navigation, look at the ["Template Parameters" Section in the documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/wayfinder)

In short:
You need a TV for your image, a snippet (see Doc) to process the TV and something like:
`<img src="[[processTV? &myId='[[+id]]' &myTV='icon' ]]" />`
in your wayfinder template

Comment: You should quote the most important parts of links. They may disappear.